# I want to switch from medical to engineering?

Tags: advisor, career-path

I want to switch from medical to engineering.
I have a bachelor degree in medical MBBS.
I am 22 yr old and really passionate about engineering,so what are the possible and practical options I have to switch my carrier ?
I even don't have mathematics in 12th standard, i had B group in 12 std.
I am in India.
I have seen a lot of posts about switching from engineering to medical, but there are not much about this.

Comment: Would you please specify the country(location)?

Comment: You might not get a satisfying answer here, because the answer is going to depend highly on your personal situation. Are you still studying? If so, does the institute you're studying at have an engineering department? Then you could ask there. If not, pick the engineering department you are most closely associated with (either by knowing someone there or having studied at the same institute) and ask there what they would advise you.

Comment: @scaaahu I m in India

Comment: I was working under a professor who did that. He did MBBS. Then he did MTech(IT) at IIT in Biomedical Engineering. Then he did PhD in Comp.Sc. You can do it.